# How to find twitter user id?

Tags: ruby, twitter

how do i get user id of a twitter user from the status id of their tweet using  the ruby twitter gem?

```
most_recent = tweets.take(30)
most_recent.each do |tweet|
    tweet_id["#{tweet.id}"] = "#{tweet.text}"
end
```

I use the code above to get the tweet ids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `tweet` is `Twitter::Tweet` object, it is easy:

```
tweet.user.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you are looking - there are several identifiers available:

```
tweet.user.screen_name  // the user's screen name
tweet.user.name         // the full name provided by user
```